# Way to edit skin in Kodi (openelec on raspberry pi)

Tags: xml, raspberry-pi3, skinning, kodi, openelec

I just downloaded a new skin for openelec and decompressed it from zip file. Customized it and compressed it into a zip, then when I'm trying to install it in Kodi (openelec on raspberry pi), it shows an error

> "addon does not have correct structure"

Please help if anyone has knowledge on this issue.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your skin. That might not be following the structure defined by Kodi as in this [link](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on_structure)

Comment: i think there is problem in zipping, because i just download a skin.confluence.zip and install it its work than i just unzip it and zip it again as it is . then i try to add but is gave me error "addon does not have correct structure"

Answer (score 0):

You likely have just the skin folder on the top zip level. Kodi needs the content to be in the top most folder.

Comment: Sorry, mixed things up. So you should open the ZIP, then see a folder named "skin.yourskin" open that and there should be your addon.xml and the other stuff.

Comment: i found these ,addon.xml and others,what next ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try zipping the addon from terminal by using and than try installing it.

```
zip -r skin.myskin.zip skin.myskin/
```

> You might be using Mac OS for development purpose which leave a file called .DS_Store inside the zip creating this problem. In this case you need to pack your addons and skins using the 'zip' comand

Comment: i did it according to this page .. but if i just unzip the skin file and zip it again it gave me same error

Comment: Which system are you using? and can you share the pastebin of the log?

Comment: raspberry pi 3 with openelecc

Comment: which operating system are you using to develop and pack the addon ?